# How to pass hashtag parameter in the URL through .htaccess 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, parameters

I have these pages on my old server with old domain name:

```
www.olddomainname.com/en/Business/Biodiversity/2ColumnSubPage/STEL_1.html
www.olddomainname.com/en/Business/Biodiversity/2ColumnSubPage/STEL_2.html
```

I will be shutting this server off, moving everything to new server with new domain name. I will keep old domain name around for redirect purposes.

On the new server i have a google like search page which is listening to the hashtag in the URL to perform a search.

Now my question is:
On .htaccess file i want to have 301 redirect script to redirect old **PAGES** from old server to a single page on the new server with new domain name and new page name **BUT** I also want to pass **name of old page** as a hashtag to new URL as well. So new URLs will look like this:

```
www.newdomainname.com/search.php#STEL_1.html
www.newdomainname.com/search.php#STEL_2.html
```

It would be awesome if the script can do batch pages.
I would really appreciate any help!

Thanks,
Zaur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/en/Business/Biodiversity/2ColumnSubPage/([^/]+\.html)$ http://www.newdomainname.com/search.php#$1
```

---

EDIT:

> Do you think we can use batch for directory part too? So even if this directory structure is different "/en/Business/Biodiversity/2ColumnSubPage/" still grab the page name from last part?

Then you'd somply want to match only the end:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /([^/]+)/(?:index\.html|)$ http://www.newdomainname.com/search.php#$1
RedirectMatch 301 /([^/]+\.html)$ http://www.newdomainname.com/search.php#$1
```

Comment: Thanks Jon! Do you think we can use batch for directory part too? So even if this directory structure is different "/en/Business/Biodiversity/2ColumnSubPage/" still grab the page name from last part? I dont want to have a line for each directory that is why. Thank you!!!

Comment: Jon you are awesome! One more question if you don't mind. In some cases link looks like this "/en/Business/Renewable/index.html" or just "/en/Business/Renewable/". Is it possible to put condition to say if you see "index.html" or no ".html" at all then pass very last directory name, in this case "Renewable"? Thank you very very much for your help!

Comment: Hi Jon, one more question if you don't mind. 
I just realized sometimes link have parameters after "index.html" like this:
`/en/About/index.html?CSB_ic-name=topMenu&CSB_ic-info=about-us_Eng`

Is it possible to avoid these pre existing parameters and not pass them to new link? Because right now it is passing "?CSB_ic-name=topMenu&CSB_ic-info=about-us_Eng" as well after folder name.
Thank you for all your help!!!